# How do I make the entire button clickable?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to put **dispay:block** or also **dispay:inline-block** but nothing seems to change.
Here is the css code of my buttons:

```
button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font color: black;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white; 
  color: black; 
  border: 2px solid #CC0000;
}
```

Comment: this should be ' clickable '. WHat do you mean it's not clickable ? share also the HTML that might show us your current situation

Comment: delete the line with: font color: black; this should just be color: black; and you already have it

Comment: The button is clickable, but only when you click the text inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Next time give here also HTML. From what you said, you have button and an "a" tag inside

switch order of tags to:

```
<a href='url'><button>Text</button></a>
```

or you can simply style  element as button

```
<a href='url' class='button'>text</a>
```